# Unit test coverage with huge string length in Go?

Tags: string, unit-testing, go, code-coverage

In some code I have a test ensuring that a string length is smaller than `2^32`. But it is difficult to test since generating a bigger string for testing would probably crash the test program with an out of memory error.

How may I achieve 100% test coverage but still testing for such case just to be safe?

Comment: I would note that very few projects in Go try to maintain 100% test coverage, simply because it's not a useful metric. You end up with useless or even broken tests that are there only for coverage, and it often forces you to refactor some code awkwardly to run the tests.

Comment: Agree. It is also possible to 100% coverage without testing everything.

Comment: I now discovered what you mean. The problem shows up when testing the error code returned by a standard lib function. It can be difficult to induce the return of an error code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refactor your code, move the limit outside of your function which tests can change:

```
var limit = 1 << 32

var ErrTooLarge = errors.New("String is too large!")

func Process(s string) error {
    if len(s) > limit {
        return ErrTooLarge
    }
    // All OK
    return nil
}
```

Testing it:

```
func TestProcess(t *testing.T) {
    // Save limit and restore it at the end:
    old := limit
    defer func() { limit = old }()

    // Test success
    if err := Process("123"); err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Expected success, got: %v", err)
    }

    // Test failure (too large string)
    limit = 5
    if err := Process("123456"); err != ErrTooLarge {
        t.Errorf("Expected ErrTooLarge, got: %v", err)
    }
}
```

Running `go test -cover`:

```
PASS
coverage: 100.0% of statements
ok      play    0.001s
```

Comment: Excellent. Didn't thought of that. My limit was a constant. So obvious once you see it.